# Set write concern for mongojs collection

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongojs

I would like to set the write concern for an entire collection using the [mongojs](https://github.com/mafintosh/mongojs) library.

This is what I think the code might look like

```
var mongojs = require('mongojs');
var db = mongojs('testdb');
var test = db.collection('test', {writeConcern: {w: 0}});
```

but I'm having a very difficult time testing if this's working or not since no matter what I pass no errors get thrown and nothing changes in the responses.

How can I change the default write concern for an entire collection or is it not even possible?

Comment: Evidently the db needs Journaling enabled to activate write concern - hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

Turns out it can be specified in the connection string as documented [here](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/connection-string/#connections-connection-options).

```
var db = mongojs('username:password@example.com/mydb?w=0', ['mycollection'])
```

Where `w=0` is setting the write concern.

Comment: It's odd.  The nodejs mongo driver seems to only allow one to set the write concern on a per-operation basis.  Meanwhile, a collection allows you to "get" the writeConcern property.  A db does too.  A db allows you to set the readConcern property (but only allows a get of writeConcern).  Go figure.  http://mongodb.github.io/node-mongodb-native/2.0/api/Db.html and http://mongodb.github.io/node-mongodb-native/2.0/api/Collection.html seem relevant.